# Do while loop not working inside a function in C

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while, cs50

I would like the below code to repeat the question "How many cents are you owed?" if the user inputs a negative answer. I've implemented a do while loop inside a function, which doesn't seem to be doing it's job and I'm not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
    int get_cents(void)
    {
        int answer;
        do
        {
            answer = get_int("How many cents are you owed? ");
            return answer;
        }
        while(answer < 0);
    }
```

Comment: `return` immediately exits the function. The loop will never loop.

Comment: The `return` statement exits the loop, and the function.  You probably want to move that after the loop.